# Invalid Markup HTML5 - stray end tag script

Tags: validation

I cannot figure out why I am receiving the below errors after trying to validate my website. On line 184, I only have the words , so I'm not sure where the language is that it is showing below.

> Line 184, Column 209: Stray end tag script.
> …b/js/hosting/cp/js_source/whv2_001.js">…
>
> Line 184, Column 209: Cannot recover after
> last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
>
> …b/js/hosting/cp/js_source/whv2_001.js">…

http://www.daleandhannah.com/CMI/site/index.html

Comment: A problem with writing a question this way is that once someone tells you what is wrong, you will fix it on your website. Then the next person who comes along will have no way of knowing, from the question, what was wrong because the markup at the end of the link validates, so the question will not be useful to future readers. Is it possible for you to create a simple, but similar, document that creates the same error and include that in the question? Alternatively, can you include relevant portions of your page in the question?

Comment: @David: The problem with creating a simple document that creates the same error is that it would probably answer the question it set out to ask :)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Create a new webpage with 184 lines and resubmit? I have no idea how to re-phrase my question. sorry.

Comment: Since the problem was found and posted in the answers below, the question does not need to be re-phrased.

Comment: The link now is gone, was better if you copied and pasted it here at time.

Answer (score 15):

You have `<script>...</script>` tags appearing AFTER the `</html>` tag in your page. That code should be moved inside the `<body>...</body>` tags.

Answer (score 12):

You got 2 `<script>` tags outside of your `<html>` tag.

```
<!-- text below generated by server. PLEASE REMOVE -->
<!-- Counter/Statistics data collection code -->
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://l.yimg.com/d/lib/smb/js/hosting/cp/js_source/whv2_001.js">
</script><script language="javascript">geovisit();</script>
<noscript><img src="http://visit.webhosting.yahoo.com/visit.gif?us1323720443" alt="setstats" border="0" width="1" height="1"></noscript>
```

Judging from the first comment, this markup is being added by your hoster. In your hosting panel, search and deactivate any "counter/statistics" tool.

Comment: judging from the coding practices the guys at yahoo seem to be using, it's no wonder everybody's using google as default search engine.

Comment: awesome. Roman, you answered my question. I turned off my site statistics and it solved my validation errors. THANKYOU for your help.

Comment: @Hannah Great! Now, you see the checkmark symbol to the left of this answer? Click it! ;)

Comment: CTRL+U in firefox or chrome or "context-(right click)-menu" -> "view source" pretty much everywhere

Comment: @HannahHarris Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if that was the solution.

Comment: @HannahHarris right below the vote count for roman's answer (currently it shows up arrow, 4, down arrow) there is a blank checkmark. Click that to make it green. This will accept the answer. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work